# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - November 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 14th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for November 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              470
2   Monomeeth                 250
3   Allan                     190
4   grg                       180
5   bmike                     130
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,727 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-11-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              170
2   bmike                      72
3   Monomeeth                  57
4   Buscar웃                   55
5   IconDaemon                 45
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,401
2   Monomeeth                 393
3   Nimesh Neema              331
4   Madhu                     306
5   Buscar웃                  287
```

A big thank you to all 58 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>**Note:** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 80
2   Nimesh Neema               70
3   Monomeeth                  61
4   Allan                      38
5   Mark                       28
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              459
2   Monomeeth                 316
3   fsb                        92
4   bmike                      66
5   Allan                      64
```

A big thank you to all 41 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               99
2   Monomeeth                  91
3   Allan                      51
4   ʀ2ᴅ2                       30
5   Glorfindel                 29
```

A big thank you to all 26 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               67
2   Allan                      58
3   Tetsujin                   35
4   Mark                       30
5   fsb                        25
```

A big thank you to all 25 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Mark                       17
2   nohillside                 16
3   Allan                      15
4   Tetsujin, Nimesh Neema     13
5   bmike                       9
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               78
2   Monomeeth                  37
3   Glorfindel                 33
4   Allan                      29
5   grg                        23
```

A big thank you to all 51 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Why does ‘freedom’ return the french fries  emoji?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/341459/168832)

   - Posted by: Besi
   - Votes: **46**
2. [Copy all the text of an entire 'man' page from Terminal.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343289/copy-all-the-text-of-an-entire-man-page-from-terminal-app)

   - Posted by: Basil Bourque
   - Votes: **18**
3. [How to find the IMEI and serial number of an iPhone before selling it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343358/how-to-find-the-imei-and-serial-number-of-an-iphone-before-selling-it)

   - Posted by: Skyler
   - Votes: **17**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Why does ‘freedom’ return the french fries  emoji?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/341488/168832)

   - Posted by: grg
   - Votes: **92**
2. [Copy all the text of an entire `man` page from Terminal.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343289/copy-all-the-text-of-an-entire-man-page-from-terminal-app/343292#343292)

   - Posted by: grg
   - Votes: **25**
3. [How to find the IMEI and serial number of an iPhone before selling it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343358/how-to-find-the-imei-and-serial-number-of-an-iphone-before-selling-it/343360#343360)

   - Posted by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **22**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Why does ‘freedom’ return the french fries  emoji?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/341459/168832)

   - Posted by: Besi
   - Views: **8,940**
2. [How can I make my iOS app “Sold Out”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341310/how-can-i-make-my-ios-app-sold-out?s=1%7C86.9900)

   - Posted by: Swift Geek
   - Views: **7,561**
3. [Should I sign open source code myself?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343912/should-i-sign-open-source-code-myself?s=1%7C101.8408)

   - Posted by: Jacob Taxén
   - Views: **2,456**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2313/mark)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Besi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13446/besi)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grg)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Besi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13446/besi)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In November our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **473 flags** with an average handling time of **20 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 244 comments
- deleted 268 posts
- closed 242 posts
- edited 214 posts
- created 67 posts
- created 489 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)